# Get upload progress for multipart upload Alamofire5

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire5

Before Alamofire5 we could user encodingReesult of uploadRequest to get `uploadProgress`.
But now after uploading Alamofire to version 5, based on [Alamofire Documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#progress), we can use `.uploadProgress` in order to get upload progress handler.

Here's my code:

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(fileContent, withName: "file", fileName: filePath.lastPathComponent)
            multipartFormData.append(token.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "token")
        }, to: uploadURL)
        .uploadProgress { progress in 
            print(progress)
        }
        .responseJSON { [weak self] response in
            print(response)
        }
```

But `uploadProgress` closure never called during upload progress.

I've checked many `stackoverflow` questions but no one worked.

Comment: I still can't find the answer. In alamofire unit test, there is a method called "executeMultipartFormDataUploadRequestWithProgress" which check if there is any upload progress. Haven't run the test on my own. But it should work with multipartFormData.

Comment: downloadProgress works though. At the end of successful upload, download progress return value "1". Only uploadProgress closure isn't being called. response callback also works.

Comment: i have posted "my fix" in the answers.

Comment: For me, uploadProgress block is only invoked once as if it was completed, but it is invoked at the start of the upload process. Later, response { } callback is invoked when upload has finished.

Answer (score 6):

If u happen to have installed a library for network traffic debugging like [Wormholy](https://github.com/pmusolino/Wormholy), then, checkout [this issue thread](https://github.com/pmusolino/Wormholy/issues/77). In short note, it's the issue with the library & uninstalling it, solves the problem. Not sure with other network debuggers though. To make things clear, try to playaround in a new, clean project and see if alamofire works in such environment.

Comment: Yes I use Wormholy network debugger. Clever answer. Let me check if it works or not

Answer (score 4):

replace your

```
.uploadProgress { progress in 
            print(progress)
        }
```

with

```
.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
})
```

it will give you output as :

```
Upload Progress: 0.035203331252732804
Upload Progress: 0.035203331252732804
Upload Progress: 0.0528049968790992
Upload Progress: 0.088008328131832
Upload Progress: 0.1584149906372976
Upload Progress: 0.2112199875163968
Upload Progress: 0.2288216531427632
Upload Progress: 0.24642331876912962
Upload Progress: 0.24642331876912962
Upload Progress: 0.24642331876912962
Upload Progress: 0.24642331876912962
Upload Progress: 0.24642331876912962
Upload Progress: 0.24642331876912962
Upload Progress: 0.24642331876912962
```

Edit :

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in
        MultipartFormData.append(fileContent, withName: "file" , fileName: filePath.lastPathComponent , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        for(key,value) in dictonary {
            MultipartFormData.append(token.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "token")
        }
    }, to: uploadURL, method: .post, headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json")

        .uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })

        .responseJSON{ (response) in
            debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
         }
```

Comment: didn't work for me. May be there's some queue dispatching problem

Comment: @AliMoazenzadeh are you running that call on main thread? 
are you sure you need to send that `token` in parameters instead of `header` from this line 
`multipartFormData.append(token.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "token")`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. token is for file not for header. and I'm running code on main thread

Comment: have you tried your API on swagger or Postman to check its working? If everything is fine and working on those and backend site do try the code I have added in above post (edited) for you to change for the AF call. @AliMoazenzadeh

Comment: Yes, server is working correctly and responseJSON block is executing every time upload finishes. Does server need any additional header to support progress? I don't think so myself @darklegend

Comment: No server doesn't needs additional headers. If your code is going on the success response then you should be able to go onto `.uploadProgress` portion of the code as well.

Comment: There's no difference between `.uploadProgress { progress in`  and `.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in`

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue.
I try to solve it by many methods.
In the end, I uninstall the pod "CocoaDebug".
It worked.
So I think maybe is CocoaDebug disturbing the network.