# Alamofire uploadProgress never called

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have the following code where I upload documents, the upload itself working fine but uploadProgress never getting called

```
do {
    let _ = fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    let file = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
    fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                
    let pendingRequest = session.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(file, withName: "file", fileName: fileUrl.lastPathComponent, mimeType: fileUrl.pathExtension)
            multipartFormData.append(typeOfDocument.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "fileType")
            multipartFormData.append(customerId.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "customerId")
            multipartFormData.append(fileId.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "fileId")
        },
        to: url,
        method: .post,
        headers: headers
    ).uploadProgress(closure: { progress in
        print(progress.fractionCompleted)
    }).responseString { response in
        guard let decodedModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UploadDocumentsResponse.self, from: response.data) else {
            completionHandler(.failure(.cannotDecode))
            return
        }
        
        completionHandler(.success(decodedModel))
    }
    return CancellableRequest(pendingRequest: pendingRequest)
} catch let error {
    fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    print(error)
    return nil
}


final class CancellableRequest {
    
    /// A Boolean value stating whether a request is cancelled.
    var isCancelled: Bool {
        pendingRequest.isCancelled
    }

    private let pendingRequest: Request
    
    init(pendingRequest: Request) {
        self.pendingRequest = pendingRequest
    }
    
    /// Cancels the represented request.
    func cancel() {
        pendingRequest.cancel()
    }
}
```

I have tried looking for a solution but couldn't find anything, looks like I am missing something obvious but can't quite figure it out what, tried uploading large file, the same result

Also tried the uploadProgress(queue, closure) the same result

Here's my Session configuration

```
self.session = Session(
    configuration: .ephemeral,
    requestQueue: DispatchQueue(label: AppConfiguration.shared.bundleId!.appending(".MyAPI"), qos: .background),
    interceptor: APIRequestInterceptor(languageManager: languageManager)
)
```

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3722#issuecomment-1553227521 ?

Comment: I found what is causing the problem, I am using wormholy library and apparently when using wormholy alamofire upload progress does not work, I removed wormholy and it started working

Comment: So you had the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/a/67260442/1801544 It seems it intercepts (I guess Swizzling?) and then take the info from "Alamofire" before reaching it. Feel free to add an answer, update the other answer and comment that WormHoly produces also the same issue. And link to https://github.com/pmusolino/Wormholy/issues/77

Answer (score 0):

I found what is causing the problem, I am using wormholy library and apparently when using wormholy alamofire upload progress does not work, I removed wormholy and it started working