Unable to get SSL and HTTP Protocol Types Using Alamofire
I'm using Alamofire in my project for networking. I need to extract data about the protocols used on the device from the requests, specifically the SSL encryption protocol type and the HTTP protocol type.
I'm utilizing Alamofire's API, which internally works with NSURLSessionTaskDelegate (specifically the URLSession:task:didFinishCollectingMetrics method) to access URLSessionTaskTransactionMetrics, which should contain these values. However, I consistently find these fields to be empty, despite their presence being confirmed through Proxyman.
Here's a general overview of the code I'm using. Can anyone suggest what the issue might be?
Or perhaps you know of other ways to obtain this data?
class AlamofireNetworkProvider {
    private let additionalHeaders: NetworkDefaultHeaders?
    private var session: Session
    
    let monitor: ClosureEventMonitor = {
        let monitor = ClosureEventMonitor()
        monitor.taskDidFinishCollectingMetrics = { session, task, metrics in
            metrics.transactionMetrics.forEach { metric in
                // do something with the metrics (URLSessionTaskMetrics)
                   print(metric.negotiatedTLSProtocolVersion)
                   print(metric.networkProtocolName)
            }
        }
        return monitor
    }()
    
    init(additionalHeaders: NetworkDefaultHeaders?) {
        self.additionalHeaders = additionalHeaders
        self.session = Session(interceptor: ConnectionLostRetryPolicy(), eventMonitors: [monitor])
    }
    
    // Executes network requests using Alamofire...
}

Alamofire version: '5.7.1'
Min supported iOS version: 15

Do you use other analytics tool? They might create issues. I remember there was a similar issue with progress download or upload and another lib was taking these infos from Alamofire (I guess by swizzling). Edit: Found the similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67192890/1801544

Also, what happens when you debugPrint the response you get back from Alamofire? That should print any metrics you have, and if those are empty too, Larme is probably right and the metrics are being swizzled somewhere.

@larme
Yes, Wormhole is indeed used in the project.
I will try to work on this and get back with the result.
Thank you very much for the advice!

@jon-shier Some fields have a value. and It looks strange.
However the version with swizzling still seems the most likely. Thank you very much.
